# 'elements[...].value' is null or not an object

Tags: html, jsp, pvcs

I am trying to modify PVCS(version manager) web version based on my needs. This product wrote in JSP.
my problem is when I add a simple combobox I receive below error and I dont know why?!
I debug the code but I couldnt get what is wrong again, kindly help me to solve the issue.

Dialog.jsp

```
Line: 281
Error: 'elements[...].value' is null or not an object
```

function that I receive error:
please find : alert(name  + " -a- "+ targetForm.elements[name].value)

```
/* copy form data from one form to another */
function copyFormData(targetForm, sourceForm)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sourceForm.elements.length; i++) {
        element = sourceForm.elements[i]
        type = sourceForm.elements[i].type
        if (type == "text" || type == "textarea" || type == "password") {
            name = sourceForm.elements[i].name

            zField = eval("targetForm['"+ name+"']");
            if ( validElement( zField ) )               
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].value
        }
        else if (type == "checkbox") {
            name = sourceForm.elements[i].name
            if (sourceForm.elements[i].checked)
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].value
        }
        else if (type == "radio") {
            name = sourceForm.elements[i].name
            if (sourceForm.elements[i].checked)
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].value
        }
        else if (type == "select-one") {
            name = sourceForm.elements[i].name
            selectedIndex = sourceForm.elements[i].selectedIndex
            alert(name  + " -a- "+ targetForm.elements[name].value)

            if (sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].value != "")
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].value
            else
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].text
        }
        else if (type == "select-multiple") {
            // FIXME_CWP - this code only handles the first selection from
            // a selection of type select-multiple.  Currently, there are
            // no cases where this is used.  Before multiple selections
            // are properly handled, a suitable delimiter must be decided
            // upon.
            // The main reason this was done was because Netscape interprets
            // a select box of size > 1 as a select-multiple
            name = sourceForm.elements[i].name
            selection = sourceForm.elements[i].options;

            selectedIndex = -1;
            for (var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++) {
                if (selection[j].selected) {
                    selectedIndex = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].value != "")
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].value
            else
                targetForm.elements[name].value = sourceForm.elements[i].options[selectedIndex].text

            //alert("selectedIndex: " + selectedIndex + "\n" + targetForm.elements[name].value);
        }
    }
}
```

CHeckout.jsp -> in this file at below line:

copyFormData(masterForm, tabForm);

masterForm is null, and that's why I receive error but why? Since page work fine without my combobox.

```
/* submit master form using elements from other forms */
function onSubmit(masterForm)
{
    // Get the check out location value.
    /*
    if (isNetscape)
        masterForm.<%=options.WORKING_FOLDER%>.value = document.general_layer.document.applets[0].getEditFieldContents();
    else
        masterForm.<%=options.WORKING_FOLDER%>.value = document.applets[0].getEditFieldContents();
    */
    //alert('Check out location=' + masterForm.<%=options.WORKING_FOLDER%>);

    // Copy the fields from the General form
    tabForm = getForm("general_form", "general_layer")
        <%-- START Added by Vamsi on 21st May 2003
    This is done as part of the Vm_secondary_performance_functional_spec
--%>
    if(tabForm.<%=options.CHECKOUT_BY_DATE_RADIO_CHOICE%>.checked)
    {
        advTabForm = getForm("advanced_form", "advanced_layer");
        advTabForm.<%=options.CHECKOUT_BY_DATE%>.checked = 1;
    }
<%-- END Added by Vamsi on 21st May 2003 --%>
    copyFormData(masterForm, tabForm);

    // Get the workfile options index from the general form and set
    // as correct value in the master form.  Note that the index numbers in
    // the switch statement correspond to the order of the select options in the form.
    selectedIndex = tabForm.<%=options.OVERWRITE_WORKITEM%>.selectedIndex;
    switch (selectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            masterForm.<%=options.OVERWRITE_WORKITEM%>.value = <%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.PROMPT_USER%>
            break;

        case 1:
            masterForm.<%=options.OVERWRITE_WORKITEM%>.value = <%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.ANSWER_YES%>
            break;

        case 2:
            masterForm.<%=options.OVERWRITE_WORKITEM%>.value = <%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.ANSWER_NO%>
            break;

        default:
            alert('Bad selected index for OVERWRITE_WORKITEM: ' + selectedIndex);
    }
    if(<%=isModelInAffect%>){
        if (document.general_form.ENABLE_LOOKUP.checked==false){
            masterForm.<%=options.LOOKUP_REVISION%>.value = "<%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.NOLOOKUP%>";
        }
    }
    else{
        masterForm.<%=options.LOOKUP_REVISION%>.value = "<%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.REVISION%>";
    }   
    // Copy the fields from the Advanced form
    tabForm = getForm("advanced_form", "advanced_layer")

    copyFormData(masterForm, tabForm);
    // Encode form data using UTF8.
    encodeFormData(masterForm, document.UTF8Encode);
    return true;
}
```

checkout.jsp   the modified part:
after I add below code I receive above error, If I remove it it is working fine!!!!!

> ```
> <tr>
>   <td>Project:</td>
>     <td>  
>       <select id="projn" name="projn">
>           <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
>           <option value="saab" SELECTED>Saab</option>
>           <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
>           <option value="audi">Audi</option>
>         </select> 
>     </td>
> </tr>
> ```

part of code

```
<DIV ID="general_layer" class="visiblelayer" ALIGN="left"><!-- general layer-->
<FORM NAME="general_form" METHOD="post" ACTION="" onSubmit="return genSubmit(this)">
 <BR>
  <TABLE BORDER="0">
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"CHECK_OUT_TO","Check Out To:")%></TD>
    <%-- <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="<%=options.WORKING_FOLDER%>" VALUE="<%=options.getStringPropertySafe(options.WORKING_FOLDER)%>" SIZE="40" MAXLENGTH="254">&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE=" ... "></TD> --%>
    <TD><%=HtmlTagHelper.writeBrowseTag("general_form",
                                        options.WORKING_FOLDER,
                                        options.getStringPropertySafe(options.WORKING_FOLDER),
                                        I18n.getStr(jspFileName, "BROWSE_TITLE_KEY", "Select Workfile Location"),
                                        browseType,
                                        45)%>
    </TD>
   </TR>

<%if (projectSelection || multiSelect)
{%>
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="<%=options.USE_WORKPATH_ATTRIBUTE%>" VALUE="false"><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"CHECK_OUT_USING_PROJECT_HIERARCHY",
                                                                                        "Check out using project hierarchy instead of workfile location(s)")%></TD>
   </TR>
<%}%>
<tr>
    <td>Project:</td>
    <td>  
        <select id="projn" name="projn">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab" SELECTED>Saab</option>
          <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select> 
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Developer:</td>
    <td>col2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Required Duration:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ID="ReqDuration" name="ReqDuration" value="5"/>Days</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>RFA No:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ID="RFANO"  name="RFANO" value="10256"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Prefered checkout location:</td>
    <td><input type="text" ID="LocationPreFix" name="LocationPreFix" value="C:\projects\"/>
        <input type="button" value="Generate Checkout Link" onClick="generateCheckout()" /></td>
</tr>
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"CHECKOUT_REVISION","Revision:")%></TD>
    <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="<%=options.REVISION%>" VALUE="<%=revision%>" SIZE="20" MAXLENGTH="254" onChange="revisionChanged()">
    <input type="button" value=" ... " onClick="window.opener.parent.browseForLabel(document.master_form,document.general_form.<%=options.REVISION%>,false,true,'<%=pvcs.vm.servlet.BrowseLabelFrameJspHelper.REVISION_VIEW%>');" onFocus="checkRevision();"/>
    </TD>

   </TR>

   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"IF_WORKFILE_EXISTS","If&nbsp;Workfile&nbsp;Exists:")%></TD>
    <TD>
     <SELECT name="<%=options.OVERWRITE_WORKITEM%>">
      <OPTION <%if (overWriteWorkItem == pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.PROMPT_USER) {%> SELECTED <%}%>><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"IF_EXISTS_PROMPT","Prompt")%>
      <OPTION <%if (overWriteWorkItem == pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.ANSWER_YES) {%> SELECTED <%}%>><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"IF_EXISTS_OVERWRITE","Overwrite")%>
      <OPTION <%if (overWriteWorkItem == pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.ANSWER_NO) {%> SELECTED <%}%>><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"IF_EXISTS_DONT_OVERWRITE","Do not overwrite")%>
      </SELECT>
     </TD>
   </TR>
<%  
    if (devPromoGroups != null)
    {
%>
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"CHECKOUT_PROMOTION_GROUP","Promotion&nbsp;Group:")%></TD>
    <TD>
     <SELECT name="<%=options.TO_PROMOTION_GROUP%>">
<%      for (int i=0; i < devPromoGroups.length; i++)
        {
%>
            <OPTION><%=devPromoGroups[i]%>
<%      }%>
      </SELECT>
    </TD>
   </TR>
<%  }%>
<%if (showAssociationsButton)
{%>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <br>
   <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="<%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"AssociateSCRS","Associate Issues")%>" onClick="onAssociateSCRs()">
  </td>
 </tr>
<% }%>
<%-- START Added by Vamsi on 22nd May 2003
    This is done as part of the Vm_secondary_performance_functional_spec. The below code is
    moved from the Advanced Tab.
--%>
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD  COLSPAN="3">
     <INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="<%=options.CHECKOUT_BY_DATE_RADIO_CHOICE%>" <%if (options.getBooleanPropertySafe(options.ONLY_IF_REVISION_NEWER, false)) {%> CHECKED <%}%> VALUE="<%=options.CHECKOUT_BY_DATE_RADIO_ONLY_IF_REVISION_NEWER%>"><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"GET_REVISION_NEWER_THAN_WORK_FILE","Get only if revision newer than workfile")%>
    </TD>
   </TR>
    <%  
    if (devPromoGroups != null )
    {
   %>
   <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD  COLSPAN="3">
         <input type="checkbox" NAME="ENABLE_LOOKUP" <%if (!disableLookup) {%> CHECKED <%}%> onClick="toggleLookupOptions();"><%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"LOOKUP_ENABLE_LABEL","Force revision lookup")%><br>   
    </TD>
    </TR>   
    <TR VALIGN="top">
    <TD  COLSPAN="3">
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="<%=options.LOOKUP_REVISION%>" value="<%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.REVISION%>" <%if (!lookupByGroup) {%> CHECKED <%}%> <%if (disableLookup) {%> DISABLED <%}%>> <%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"LOOKUP_REV_LABEL","Based on Revision")%><br>
     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="<%=options.LOOKUP_REVISION%>" value="<%=pvcs.cmd.PvcsConst.GROUP%>" <%if (lookupByGroup) {%> CHECKED <%}%> <%if (disableLookup) {%> DISABLED <%}%>> <%=I18n.getStr(jspFileName,"LOOKUP_GROUP_LABEL","Based on Promotion Group")%>       
    </TD>
   </TR>
   <%}%>
<%-- END --%>
 </TABLE>
 <BR>
</FORM>
</DIV>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that in that page there are several hidden filed that "copyFormData" function get a copy of all the fields and store it there, so that's why my new fields were not available there so I received null error.